# How to create fake PHP directory that mapped to another PHP directory?

Tags: php

For example, I have a folder `web.com/app/resource/css/` and from browser perspective I want the user to be able to access this folder via url `web.com/css/` instead of `web.com/app/resource/css/`. How do I accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css app/resources/css/ [QSA,NC,L]
```